# GLSL shader time uniform freezed?

Tags: opengl, shaders, opengl-es2, ogre

I have a simple fragment shader to simulate "falling water". I'm using Ogre3D and opengles2, this is my code:

```
#version 130

uniform sampler2D valveTex;
uniform sampler2D noiseTex;
uniform float time;

uniform vec3 sprayColor;

varying vec2 uv;
varying float rand;

    void main()
    {
        gl_FragColor.w = texture2D(valveTex, uv).w;
        float noiseW = texture2D(noiseTex, uv + vec2(rand, -time)).x;
        gl_FragColor.w *= noiseW + noiseW;
        gl_FragColor.xyz = sprayColor;
    }
```

The shader works well and I see the animation happening, but after some time running the animation stops like if the variable `time` stopped updating, and the water stream looks still. What can be causing this?

**Edit1:** variable `time` is derived from Ogre's `time_0_1`.

Comment: Can you confirm what wrapping mode you've configured for your noiseTex?

Comment: On my material file noiseTex is `tex_address_mode wrap wrap`

Comment: Hm, then we'll need to do some more troubleshooting. Can you print some values of time before and after the animation stops?

Comment: Ok, I'll try since it's quite random, sometimes the animation breaks after 15 minutes or so and on other cases it takes several hours, I have one test running since last Friday and it still works.

Comment: Hm. Sounds like the root cause is unlikely to be your shader code, then. Maybe something's going awry CPU-side where you update the uniform?

Comment: On that case I should dig into Ogre's source because my variable `time` is derived from Ogre's `time_0_1` which the engine should automatically update... right?

Comment: I'm not an Ogre expert myself, but if you add the [tag:ogre] tag above and edit your question to detail how you've set up the effect in Ogre, a user more experienced with the engine might be able to offer a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your `noiseTex` you're looking up into might be configured with wrapping mode `CLAMP_TO_EDGE` - once your `time` uniform gets large enough to take it outside the [0, 1] texture coordinate range, texture samples start just repeating the same values they had at the edge of the texture.

Ensure your texture is a power of two in size and configured with wrapping mode `REPEAT`.